# Manipulating static data from hashmap

Tags: java, static-methods

So below is code I was given and told to work with.

I don't have much experience with Java but I do have some understanding when it comes to OOP.

I have a hashmap with stock items prices and quantity and I would like to be able to display all those variables, add them to a list and to have access to price etc in different classes. I've read the documentation and a lot of websites and it still isn't clear to me how to use such data.

```
public class StockData {

    public static class Item {

        Item(String n, double p, int q) {
            name = n;
            price = p;
            quantity = q;
        }

        // get methods
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public double getPrice() {
            return price;
        }

        public int getQuantity() {
            return quantity;
        }

        // instance variables 
        private final String name;
        private final double price;
        private int quantity;
    }
    private final static Map<String, Item> stock = new HashMap();

    static {
        // if you want to have extra stock items, put them in here
        // use the same style - keys should be Strings
        stock.put("00", new Item("Bath towel", 5.50, 10));
        stock.put("11", new Item("Plebney light", 20.00, 5));
        stock.put("22", new Item("Gorilla suit", 30.00, 7));
        stock.put("33", new Item("Whizz games console", 50.00, 8));
        stock.put("44", new Item("Oven", 200.00, 4));
    }
    public static Map<String, Item> getStock() {
        return stock;
       }
    public static String getName(String key) {
        Item item = stock.get(key);
        if (item == null) {
            return null; // null means no such item
        } else {
            return item.getName();
        }
    }

    public static double getPrice(String key) {
        Item item = stock.get(key);
        if (item == null) {
            return -1.0; // negative price means no such item
        } else {
            return item.getPrice();
        }
    }

    public static int getQuantity(String key) {
        Item item = stock.get(key);
        if (item == null) {
            return -1; // negative quantity means no such item
        } else {
            return item.getQuantity();
        }
    }
    public static void update(String key, int extra) {
        Item item = stock.get(key);
        if (item != null) {
            item.quantity += extra;
        }
    }

    public static void close() {
        // Does nothing for this static version.
        // Write a statement to close the database when you are using one
    }

}
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear.

Comment: @Perdomoff I don't know how to access this data from a different class so for example if i wanted to display all items with prices and quantities how would I do something like that

Comment: You can iterate threw a HashMap. There is no need for list. See [link](http://www.sergiy.ca/how-to-iterate-over-a-map-in-java/) Also i don't like the OOP in the code. Move Item to a separate file. Stop using static, i don't think you need it here?

Comment: @Heinzlmaen how do I for example put the names in a JComboBox and then depending on what user chose I get the quantity and price? and also read the question the code was given to me as is.

Comment: If your question is how to access `class Item` which is a static nested class inside `class StockData` then the answer is its FQN is `StockData.Item`. Since `Item` is `public` it is accessible everywhere `StockData` is. If `StockData` is not in the default package but instead in some named `package `p` then the FQN would be `p.SotckData.Item`

Answer (score 1):

You can access this data from anywhere because it's defined statically.  For instance, you can write a Sandbox class to run a main function like this:

```
public class Sandbox {
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {

        for(String key : StockData.getStock().keySet()) {
            System.out.println("Item: " + key);

            System.out.println("Name: " + StockData.getName(key) +
                    "  Price: " + StockData.getPrice(key) +
                    " Qty: " + StockData.getQuantity(key));
        }
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
Item: 00
Name: Bath towel  Price: 5.5 Qty: 10
Item: 11
Name: Plebney light  Price: 20.0 Qty: 5
Item: 22
Name: Gorilla suit  Price: 30.0 Qty: 7
Item: 33
Name: Whizz games console  Price: 50.0 Qty: 8
Item: 44
Name: Oven  Price: 200.0 Qty: 4
```

Comment: so now for example I display all this data and i have dropdown with names of items and user wants to add to the quantity of Bath Towel 2 so it would be 12 how would I update the whole thing that is displayed

Comment: You'd use the static update(...) method that's provided in Stock Data: `StockData.update("00", 2);`  Note that the code for the update method increments the existing quantity, so you want to pass in the difference, not the total.

Comment: yeah that part I do get but how would I update the table that is displayed so e.g. I have JTextField with all the data that you showed and somebody adds 2 I want it to show immidiately in that JTextField

Comment: You'll want to do some reading on Swing [JTextField](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html)

Comment: is there an easy way maybe different to display such data and quickly update the whole thing im displaying? maybe I should put this whole data in a list and then display it

Comment: You already have the Item class defined by the provided static classes.  You can use that class to store this information if necessary.  Placing it in a list within your GUI code is a possibility, but remember that means you have to update your GUI list if the backing list ever changes.